# Oracle - How to get date from YEAR, WEEKNUM and WEEKDAY?

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I need to find the date of particular year, week, and weekday in oracle. 
Is there a built-in function for this in oracle? or how can I achieve this?

Ex: If Year=2019, Week=22, Day=2(Tuesday), Then date should be '28-05-2019'.

Comment: How do you define "Week" - there are several definitions, see [Week numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no built-in function for this, you will have to build one on your own.
below is one of the solutions you can make use of.

```
WITH FUNCTION getDate(p_year IN NUMBER, p_weeks IN NUMBER, p_day in NUMBER) RETURN DATE
IS
  v_tmp date;
  v_day number;
BEGIN
  v_tmp := to_date('01/01/'||to_char(p_year),'dd/mm/yyyy'); 
  v_day := to_char(v_tmp,'D');

  RETURN v_tmp+(p_weeks-1)*7+p_day-(v_day)+1;
END;
SELECT getDate(2019,22,2)
FROM DUAL;
/
```

As per my NLS_TERRITORY settings, Oracle numbers the day of the week starting from Sunday, but from your example, you seem to be considering Monday as day 1 of the week. So, the same adjustment is made to the function to return the expected result.

Also, please note that with clause function is a new feature of Oracle 12c, if you happen to use an older version of Oracle, you will have to create the stored function before calling it.

Comment: "Oracle numbers the day of the week starting from Sunday" is not correct. It depends on the current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` setting.

Comment: I was unaware of it. Thanks, @WernfriedDomscheit for the clarification.

Comment: This function does not work for all dates. For example `2016-W52` is week from `2016-12-26` to `2017-01-01` (according to ISO 8601). `getDate(2016,52,2)` returns `2016-12-20` but it should be `2016-12-27`

Comment: I think it depends on how we number a week of the year.
Few websites are considering Dec 28,2015 to Jan 3, 2016 as Week 53 of year 2015. if so, week 52 would be from 26-Dec-2016 to 01-Jan-2017.
But if we consider the week of 01-Jan-2016 as the first week of the day, irrespective of the day, week 52 would be from 19-Dec-2016 to 25-Dec-2016.

Comment: Excel also has a function WEEKNUM to return week number of a specific date, it also returns 20-12-2016 as week 52.
WEEKNUM("20-dec-2016")

Comment: Yes, that's the reason for my first question **How do you define "Week"** - which is still unanswered.

Comment: I think, for the given example input and output to be satisfied, the below criteria must be met.
1. Start week numbering from the week of 01-Jan, irrespective of the day.
2. Days in a week should be numbered from Monday instead of Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "Week" and "Year" means week and year according to [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) you can use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISOWeekDate(YEAR INTEGER, WEEK INTEGER, DAY INTEGER) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
    res DATE;
BEGIN
    IF WEEK > 53 OR WEEK < 1 THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;      
    END IF;

    res := NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( YEAR || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY') + ( WEEK - 1 ) * 7;

    IF TO_CHAR(res, 'fmIYYY') = YEAR THEN
        RETURN res + DAY - 1;
    ELSE
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;
END ISOWeekDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the ISO week number is the occurrence of Thursdays in that (Gregorian) calendar year. The ISO year of an ISO week, is the Gregorian year in which the Thursday of that ISO week falls.

In the ISO schema, weeks always contain 7 days. Weeks start on a Monday, finish on a Sunday, and the days of that week are numbered 1-7.

This weekday numbering scheme often differs from that returned from built-in `WEEKDAY` functions and similar in different software packages (or requires particular database settings), which is something to be aware of. You will need available a function that returns the weekday of a particular date according to the ISO numbering scheme.

The first Thursday of the year can occur anywhere in the range 01-Jan to 07-Jan.

If the first Thursday falls on 01-Jan, then the first ISO week of that year will include days (29/31-Dec) from the previous Gregorian year.

If the first Thursday falls on 07-Jan, then the last ISO week of the previous Gregorian year will include days (01/03-Jan) from the current Gregorian year.

If the first Thursday falls on 04-Jan, then by implication the first ISO week of the year runs from Monday 01-Jan.

To devise an algorithm, the easiest approach is probably to establish on what weekday the 04-Jan falls in the given year, then apply the following calculation `4 - weekday`. If the weekday of 04-Jan is found to be Thursday, the result will be 0. If it is Monday, the result will be 3 (4-1). If it is Sunday, the result will be -3 (4-7). We will store this offset for use after the next step.

We can derive a provisional day-of-year-offset from the ISO week and day numbers as follows: `(((iso_week - 1) * 7) - (4 - iso_day))`.

We then apply the offset derived in the first stage for the final day-of-year-offset. This is an offset from 04-Jan of the given Gregorian year. This offset may be a minus figure, if the relevant day falls prior to 04-Jan of the given year.

Given that day-of-year-offset, we can then use built-in functions to produce 04-Jan of the given year, and apply the day-of-year-offset to produce the final Gregorian date.

For example, given 2019-W01-1.

2019-01-04 is a Friday, so it's weekday is 5. The result of the first step is -1 (4-5). The result of the second step is -3 (((1-1)*7) - (4-1)). Added together they produce a day-of-year-offset of -4. 04-Jan-2019 offset by -4 results in 31-Dec-2018.

And that is our result: 2019-W01-1 = 2018-12-31.